# How to do json formatting using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to convert the input json to the expected output format.

### input json:

```
[
    {
        "key 1": "value 1",
        "key 2": "value 2",
        "key 3": "value 3",
        "key 4": "value 4",
    },
    {
        "key 1": "value 1",
        "key 2": "value 2",
        "key 3": "value 5",
        "key 4": "value 6",
    },
    {
        "key 1": "value 1",
        "key 2": "value 2",
        "key 3": "value 7",
        "key 4": "value 8",
    }
]
```

### output json:

```
[
    {
        "key 1": "value 1",
        "key 2": "value 2",
        "key 3": "value 3, value 5, value 7",
        "key 4": "value 4, value 6, value 8"
    }
]
```

### logic :

Check value for key 1 and key 2, if they are same, merge all json elements into one and join key 3 and key 4 as comma separated strings.

Comment: Please visit the[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Show what you have tried and where you are stuck. When practical post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
const input=
[ { "key 1": "value 1","key 2": "value 2","key 3": "value 3","key 4": "value 4"},
  { "key 1": "value 1","key 2": "value 2","key 3": "value 5","key 4": "value 6"},
  { "key 1": "value 1","key 2": "value 2","key 3": "value 7","key 4": "value 8"} ];

let acc=input.reduce((acc,obj)=>{
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((ac,[k,v])=>{
    (ac[k]=ac[k] || {})[v]=1;
    return ac;
  }, acc);
}, {});

let output=[ Object.entries(acc).reduce((a,[k,v])=>(a[k]=Object.keys(v).join(', '),a),{}) ];
console.log(output);
```

Comment: thank you... this worked :-)